# Ruby on Rails JSON serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization

I'm a complete newcomer to Ruby on Rails so please forgive me if this is an obvious question.

I'm returning a JSON object from a controller method (let's say the class name is "foo" and it has a property "bar").

I'd expected this to serialize as:

```
{"bar" : "barValue" }
```

However, it seems to serialize as

```
{"foo" : {"bar" : "barValue"}}
```

This seems out of joint with a.) what other languages do , b.) (More importantly) what javascript does.

Say I've defined the same class foo in Javascript:

```
var fooInstance = new Foo();
fooInstance.bar = "barValue";
```

And I then stringify that using one of a Javascript JSON library (e.g. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js ). Then the output is something along the lines of:

```
{"bar" : "barValue" }
```

But inputs (as well as outputs) to my controller methods expect:

```
{"foo" : {"bar" : "barValue"}
```

So I have to write code along these lines to make it work:

```
var fooInstance = new Foo();
fooInstance.bar = "barValue";
var dummyObjectToKeepRailsHappy = { foo : fooInstance};
```

So- am I doing Rails serialization incorrectly? Or is there a reason it works this way?

Comment: If you're working with ActiveRecord objects, you can set `config.active_record.include_root_in_json = false` in application.rb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read up the documentation on Rails `to_json` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json).

> The option
>   ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json
>   controls the top-level behavior of
>   to_json. In a new Rails application,
>   it is set to true in
>   initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb.
>   When it is true, to_json will emit a
>   single root node named after the
>   object’s type.

So adding to your environment/application.rb

```
config.active_record.include_root_in_json = true
```

should solve your issues.